# Grade Problem while running the Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running the flutter application but this shows this error

```
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2902)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2811)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1927)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

use vpn or proxy on your system
after that run

```
flutter clean
```

when it done
run

```
flutter pub get
```

in terminal